# ASP .NET MVC 3 controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to register Controller in MVC3?

I have 2 solutions:

- MvcApplication (MVC 3 Web Application) with file 'HomeController.cs'
- CustomController (Class library) with file 'CustomController.cs'

If i Build 'CustomController' solution and Add reference in MvcApplication solution to this, i can simple use CustomController in application. But how i can do it without 'Add reference' action, just with Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToDll) e.t.c.?

Comment: Why don't you want to have to `Add Reference...` for your main project solution?

Comment: Is it possible to make 'Add Reference' action when i've already published my project and load it to server folder?

Comment: Are you not able to Add Reference and then republish the project??  Down time will be minimal, and you won't have to worry about this workaround in the future.

Comment: I'd like to let users upload plugins into my project when it's already compiled and loaded to server in inetpub.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Then it looks like wnascimento's answer may be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MEF for that.

See a good article

[http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-(MEF).aspx](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx)

This section in your global.asax, register the new controller fac and set the "Plugins" folder for MEF load their libraries. Plugins folder is in your asp.net app root folder.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory( 
new MefControllerFactory( 
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins")));
```

Comment: I'm not sure it should work, but let's see.    this.catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginPath); 
    this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

Comment: With MEF you can enable the use of plugins. pluginPath is the path where the MEF should seek their compiled libraries(dll). (mvc_app_folder/plugins) for example